# What is the best way to set up a CI/CD pipeline on ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

There are so many options:

- Docker-compose with ECS cli looks the easiest solution
- Terraform
- CloudFormation (looks complex!)
- Ansible

I am only interested in setting up a basic ECS docker set-up with ELB and easily updating the Docker image version.

We all love technology here, but we're not all super geniuses when it comes to tech. So I'm looking to keep my set-up as simple as possible. We run Jenkins, 2 NodeJS applications, 2 Java applications in ECS and I know it involves IAM, Security Groups, EBS, ELB, ECS Service/Task, ECS Task Definition, but that already gets complex quickly in CloudFormation.

What are good technologies that will allow us to use Docker, keep things simple and don't require us to be very intelligent to understand our own programming code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start by trying to setup your pipeline using Terraform. Learning it will give you experience in a non-vendor specific infrastructure as code.

Another possibility is to avoid using CloudFormation directly and prefer using the AWS CDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html) as IaC.

Best regards